# stuck queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, processlist

[image]

This is a screenshot of the process list of my MySQL DB. There are queries which are stuck for the past 20000+ seconds. I know there are issues in the code.
My question is, is there any way to know which queries are these?

I am new to this . . . any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: these queries are not getting recorded in slow query logs.

Comment: THis question is probably out of topic here and should be on Super User site

Answer (score 0):

There are no queries here.  `Sleep` means these are open connections waiting for the next request.